# How to rewrite function, without using lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have one library, which is written with c++11 standard(at least) and my compiler which is c++0x.
Library contains some functions, that i have to revert to c++0x.
Since i have no experience with lambda expressions, i am stuck at rewriting the following function:

```
void EventTrace::connect(Connector& connector)
{
    Connector::EventSignal& s = connector.getEventSignal();
    connection_ = s.connect(
        [this](int e)
        {
            if (decoders_.empty())
            {
                poco_information_f1(LOGGER(), "Event %d", e);
            }
            for (Decoder decoder : decoders_)
            {
                try
                {
                    decoder(e);
                }
                catch (Exception& exception)
                {
                    poco_warning_f1(LOGGER(), "EventTrace Decoder error %s", exception.displayText());
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question: what are you trying to achieve? What did you try? The code looks good to me; why rewrite it?

Comment: Let me understand: do you want convert C++11 code to C++0x code?

Comment: yes, i need to convert c++11 code to c++0x, because i have c++0x compiler. And upgrading compiler is not an option because it is more work, and seniors do not wish to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda is just (in C++) syntactic sugar around an anonymous struct/class with an `operator()`.

In pre-C++11 code you can replace the lambda by one of those struct, for example:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(EventTrace* e): e_(e) {}
    void operator()(int t) {
        // the inside of the lambda
        // you just have to replace implicit usage of this by e_->...
    }
};
void EventTrace::connect(Connector& connector)
{
    Connector::EventSignal& s = connector.getEventSignal();
    Foo f(this);
    connection_ = s.connect(f);
}
```

Comment: Your operator() has the wrong signature, should take an int.

Comment: yes it should, thanks for the correction.